# R unary operator overload: risks?

Tags: r, operator-overloading

In my continuing quest to avoid using parentheses for some simple commands, I wrote up the following operator to create a new graphics window.  My question is: am I at risk of "breaking" anything in R, other than the obvious inability to execute the "not" function on my variable "newdev"?

```
# function to overload "!" for one purpose only
#this is adapted  from the sos package code for "???", credited to Duncan Murdoch.
# Example of how to create a specialized unary  operator that doesn't require
# parentheses for its argument.  So far as I can tell,  
#the only way to do this is to overload an existing function or
# operator which doesn't require parentheses.  "?" and "!" meet this requirement.
`!` <- function (e1, e2)  { 
call <- match.call()
#  match.call breaks out each callable function in argument list (which was "??foo" for the sos package "???",
 #  which allows topicExpr1 to become  a list variable w/ callable function "!"  (or "?" in sos) 
original <- function() { 
    call[[1]]<-quote(base::`!`)
    return(eval(call, parent.frame(2)))
}

   # this does preclude my ever having an actual
   # variable called "newdev" (or at least trying to create the actual NOT of it) 
if(call[[2]] =='newdev') {
    windows(4.5,4.5,restoreConsole=T)
}else{
    return(original())  # do what "!" is supposed to do 
}
}
```

Comment: Would you just be using these simple commands directly at the command prompt (i.e., not embedding them in functions or whatnot)? If so, you could create a new class and define a print method for that class that would do what you wanted.

Comment: I think there's a good chance I'd call these commands inside a function, if I wanted to create a collection of charts, e.g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I executed `"!" = function(a){stop("'NOT' is used")}` and executed the `replications` function, which uses the ! operator, and this worked fine. So it looks like it is safe to override "!".

Still you probably want to use classes, which you can do as follows:

```
# Create your object and set the class
A = 42
class(A) = c("my_class")

# override ! for my_class
"!.my_class" = function(v){ 
  cat("Do wathever you want here. Argument =",v,"\n")
}

# Test ! on A
!A
```

Comment: Good point, although this won't work for my intended purpose, which was to execute a particular closure which doesn't require an argument without having to type "()" after it.  As an example, `!ls` instead of `ls()` .  And, yes, I'm lazy that way :-). (remember, the default behaivor in `R` if you type just the name of a closure is to print the closure code to the console)

Comment: To add to this: functions defined interactively or in your `.Rprofile` go in `globalenv()` -- functions in packages can't see them. But, any *other* functions you may have in your `.RProfile` will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
makeActiveBinding
```

you can replace ls() by e.g LS w/o need of unary operators

Comment: That's a good point, and in fact one I use for a few "quickie" functions.  I just ended up preferring the method posted because I rewrote it with a `switch` function -- see the source code for `splatnd` in the package `cgwtools` .