# Is it possible to get F#'s function application "|>" operator in R?

Tags: r, f#, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R Pipelining functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354048/r-pipelining-functions)

I find R syntax very unwieldy compared to F#:

In R - Instead of:

```
plot(exp(cumsum(returns)))
```

I would love to do

```
returns |> cumsum |> exp |> plot
```

Is there a way to overload an operator in R to achieve a similar effect?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

sure, why not,

```
`%|>%` = function(x, y) y(x)
1:10 %|>% cumsum %|>% plot
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Comment: careful though, my gut feeling is that it's little recommendable

Comment: @baptiste: Why not?

Answer (score 5):

Stolen from the `Reduce` help page:

```
Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)
Reduce(Funcall, list(plot, exp, cumsum), 1:10, right = TRUE)
```

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that it's easier to read (at least for users of R, Matlab, scipy, etc) and overall easier to "drop into" existing R functions designed for recursive and repetitive operations (e.g. `*apply`).  THen again, I'm the wiseguy who overloaded `!` as seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195165/r-unary-operator-overload-risks

Comment: can anyone recommend a way to come up with a shorter operator than %|>% is?

Comment: It's difficult to imagine a shorter version than babtiste's given the manner in which functions get defined in R. And given the "closed" nature of this question, you should be posting comments in answers to an open question.

Comment: @nxstock-trader  You could define any `%[char]%` you wanted, or follow my link to an overload for `![char]`